# How to create a drop down list in java without swing using panel?

Tags: java, drop-down-menu, awt

I have to figure out how to create a drop down panel without using swing. Is anything like this online? Can anyone send me a link. Point me in a good direction.

I can use AWT.

Comment: Probably not, since most people would simply use the built-in Swing Combobox rather than build their own.

Comment: So what ARE you allowed to use? SWT? AWT? Or are you just being asked to implement an alternative to JComboBox that still uses Swing drawing operations?

Comment: What exactly do you understand with *drop down panel*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AWT has the Choice class.

```
Choice myChoice = new Choice();
```

Comment: That's what I thought but I can't seem to locate it in the api under java.awt.Panel. Am I missing something? Can you tell me where you see Choice? Is it inherited from a parent? (http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/)

Comment: Choice is a proper Component not related to Panel, and looks similar to a JComboBox in Swing (though JComboBox is more flexible). This is used for "dropdown lists" - it may or may not be what you want. I don't know the term "dropdown panel".

Comment: java.awt.Choice is a subclass of java.awt.Component, java.awt.Panel is a subclass of java.awt.Container wich is a subclass of java.awt.Component too. 
Containers are a special kind of component that have the ability to contain and organize another components. 
So the relation between Panel and Choice is that you can add a Choice into a Panel. :)